# Can we create mutiple test run for a single project in devicefarm

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-espresso, aws-cli, aws-device-farm

I am using `aws devicefarm` to run my android tests, and absolutely loved it.

So everytime I run my script it creates a new project in my account but I don't want to do that. I just want to create single project in my account with all the testruns. Name of the test run will be combined with timestamp for more clarity. Is it possible to do that in devicefarm?

I use the following arn to start schedule my test:

To schedule a run, following input parameters are needed:

- project-arn
- app-arn
- testPackageArn
- device-pool-arn

I tried to keep the same `project_arn` to schedule my test but it is still creating a new project which I don't want. I just want a new test run inside the same project. I will appreciate if you give some inputs.

[Blog I followed to run my tests](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxROO0QM0WSCJX/Get-started-with-the-AWS-Device-Farm-CLI-and-Calabash-Part-1-Creating-a-Device-F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `create-project` multiple times (step #1 in the [linked blog post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxROO0QM0WSCJX/Get-started-with-the-AWS-Device-Farm-CLI-and-Calabash-Part-1-Creating-a-Device-F)).

What you should do is call `create-project` once and store the project ARN. Reuse this project ARN in subsequent ScheduleRun calls.